# Sample from ragged tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, ragged-tensors

I have a raggedTensor of row_lens going from 1 to up to 10k. I would like to select elements randomly from it with an upper limit on the number per row in a scalable way. Like in this example:

```
vect = [[1,2,3],[4,5][6],[7,8,9,10,11,12,13]]
limit = 3
sample(vect, limit)
```

->  output: [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,9,11]]

My idea was to select * in case len_row < limit and randomly in the other case. I wonder if this can be done with less than batch_size complexity with some tensorflow operations?

Comment: How do you get `[7,9,11]` in your output?

Comment: Picking 3 randomly, could be `[9,10,13]` if you want

Comment: You want to sample from every row?

Comment: Exactly. The code should be in Tensorflow and executable in graph mode. This is were I'm stuck

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you

Comment: Related to your answer, I had to add @tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True), otherwise every time the function is called with different shapes, tracing is re-executed

Comment: Hey, @AloneTogether, I wanted to update because actually I run into an issue from tensorflow (2.7).
Setting up the samplng with the map in graph mode throws a `ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.` exception. I tried to remove the tf.function decorator and move the sample inside and outside the class but with no chage. It seems tensorflow cannot understand the shapes for the graph execution (it runs in jupyter and in init) Do you know f there is a problem with map_fn, graph execution and sparse tensors?

Comment: added `fn_output_signature=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(ragged_rank=0, dtype=tf.int32))` but no fix

Comment: you have to add all dimension to the `tf.RaggedTensorSpec`. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557245/how-to-slice-according-to-batch-in-the-tensorflow-array/70558892#70558892 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70419275/apply-linear-algebra-to-ragged-tensor-in-tensorflow/70420897#70420897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `tf.map_fn` in graph mode:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

vect = tf.ragged.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[7,8,9,10,11,12,13]])

@tf.function
def sample(x, samples=3):
  length = tf.shape(x)[0]
  x = tf.cond(tf.less_equal(length, samples), lambda: x, lambda: tf.gather(x, tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(length))[:samples]))
  return x

c = tf.map_fn(sample, vect)
```

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [12, 7, 9]]>
```

Note that `tf.vectorized_map` would probably be faster, but there is a current [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51771) regarding this function and ragged tensors. The use of `tf.while_loop` is also an option.